# How to use QgsOverlayAnalyzer class in pyQGIS?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, intersection

I am very new to Python scripting in QuantumGIS, so bear with me please.

I am trying to use the QgsOverlayAnalyzer class in QuantumGIS (http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsOverlayAnalyzer.html#details) to automate the intersection between different layers (I have plenty of intersections to do).

However, I can't get it to work in the python console.. assume I want to intersect layer1 with layer2, and write the results in `C:\shapefile.shp`, I am trying something like this with no success:

```
QgsOverlayAnalyzer.intesection(layer1, layer2, "C:\shapefile.shp", false, 0)
```

The error I make must be quite serious, as the message I get is:

```
NameError: name 'QgsOverlayAnalyzer' is not defined
```

Any help on this is very much appreciated.

Dom

Answer (score 5):

It seems that the correct answer is [here](http://osgeo-org.1560.n6.nabble.com/How-to-apply-intersection-of-layers-in-Python-plugin-script-td5029680.html).

You can access to that object importing the analysis module:

```
from qgis import analysis
qgis.analysis.QgsOverlayAnalyzer
```

Comment: Diegogb, thanks a lot! this is exactly what I was looking for, now it runs like a charme! Quite depressing though that yesterday I surfed the web for a few hours without managing to come across the page you linked me!